# How to get the "publish_post" equivalent

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

**Scenario**

I'm building an application that needs the ability to post to users wall (personal profile) on behalf of a user on facebook. I remember before the way that I would do it is request a permission "publish_actions" but reading through their documentation i came to this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/#login-4-24

which states that that is being deprecated.

They recommended an alternative which is using their sharing product found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) but this seems like it would break one of the functionalies of my current application (I dont want to share content i want users to post it to whenever they choose to on whichever account they choose to).

**Question**

Is there a way to get posting to a users wall and NOT an event, page or group. If i'm correct I can still post data to events, pages and groups via API as normal but to a users wall its different? I need to post on their wall via api but i can't seem to find the permission.

My facebook api graph version for my app is 3.0 and im using their PHP SDK to make the requests.

Comment: "on whichever account they choose to" - not sure what that means, one user can only have one account. either way, i believe it´s just not possible anymore.

Comment: @luschn A human can have multiple facebook accounts, the app im building lets them manage their facebook accounts, thats what i meant i should have been more clear. but i think youre right the more i look into it the more i see its not possible...

Comment: you are only allowed to have ONE facebook account.

Comment: _“A human can have multiple facebook accounts”_ - not if they don’t want to violate Facebook’s terms to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe well thats not up to me whether or whether not people choose to have multiple different accounts for whatever reason, the reality is its a thing. Other than being completely besides the point how is that comment useful?

Comment: If Facebook still wanted you to be able to post to user timelines, resp. in the name of the user, then they would most likely not have removed this permission in the first place. So now you can either try and adapt to use sharing functionality in some way; or simply accept that the business model of your app is not suitable any more.

Comment: Ah well good thing I can still do pages and events and groups then, it'll take more than just users feed to cause the app any problems, its more of an inconvenience.